# How does android handle duplicated schemes

Tags: android, android-intent

Consider two apps, both registered for the same scheme "appscheme". When this scheme is triggered, which app will get called? I know for IOS, the scheme that was registered first will get triggered. Does the same rule apply to Android?

Comment: ANdroid doesn't have "scheme"s.  What's the android concept you're referring to?

Comment: you can associate a scheme with the intent filter

Comment: Ok.  No, the same rule does not apply.  An app can create a chooser to let the user choose between some/all of the options.  Or if its for an action with a mime type (such as ACTION_VIEW), it will have a default for the mime type that the user can set and change.